# AR mobile Unity Multiplayer spawn multiple cameras relative to one another

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality

I want to make my own node.js multiplayer server for an Android AR Unity game. The game will have up to three players. I am wondering how to get each of the player cameras to spawn on the same plane relative to one another, without using a predefined spawn point. So if the players start 10 feet from one another in the real world, the cameras will spawn in that relative distance to one another, sharing the same local space, so that players can see each other and also remain the same objective distance from objects spawned in the scene. Does it have something to do with MakeContentAppearAt? Or do I need to use fixed spawn points? I think I understand how to do it if there are fixed spawn points, but it doesn't make sense to me that the spawn points could be fixed while real world AR starting positions for people holding phones would be dynamic.

Edit: it appears i'd also need to make the rotation of each camera match in the unity world coordinates. https://github.com/MichaelTaylor3D/UnityGPSConverter seems like it might work for position? What do you think? What about rotation? Also converting the GPS system to Unity coordinates wouldn't give me the Y-axis value of the camera position. Let's say I want weapon prefabs to sync according to the locations of each camera.